Ignore authorization for a particular URL in Spring Cloud API Gateway
I have an API Gateway that routes to an Netflix Eureka Discover Server in Spring. I have configured an authorization for the API Gateway but wanted to ignore this API Gateway authorization only for the discover server.
I am using <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion> and <spring-cloud.version>2023.0.1</spring-cloud.version> and spring version 3.2.4
This is my Security Config for the API Gateway
package config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.reactive.EnableWebFluxSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.server.SecurityWebFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity serverHttpSecurity) {

        serverHttpSecurity
                .csrf(ServerHttpSecurity.CsrfSpec::disable)
                .authorizeExchange(exchange -> exchange.pathMatchers("/eureka/**")
                        .permitAll()
                        .anyExchange()
                        .authenticated())
                .oauth2ResourceServer(spec -> spec.jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()));
        return serverHttpSecurity.build();
    }
}


This is how I configured the routes for the API Gateway
## Discover Server Route
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[2].id=discovery-server
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[2].uri=http://localhost:8761
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[2].predicates[0]=Path=/eureka/web
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[2].filters[0]=SetPath=/

I have configured it to allow "/eureka/" but still I get an 401 error saying unauthorized access.
authorizeExchange(exchange -> exchange.pathMatchers("/eureka/**")
                        .permitAll()
                        .anyExchange()

Have I configured it wrong?
Do I need to configure something in the Eureka Server?
These are the logs I get when I try to access the Eureka server through the API gateway.
2024-04-14T14:54:22.207-07:00 DEBUG 35903 --- [api-gateway] [ctor-http-nio-2] .s.s.w.s.u.m.AndServerWebExchangeMatcher : Trying to match using org.springframework.security.web.server.csrf.CsrfWebFilter$DefaultRequireCsrfProtectionMatcher@125741b8
2024-04-14T14:54:22.208-07:00 DEBUG 35903 --- [api-gateway] [ctor-http-nio-2] .s.s.w.s.u.m.AndServerWebExchangeMatcher : Did not match
2024-04-14T14:54:22.214-07:00 DEBUG 35903 --- [api-gateway] [     parallel-3] o.s.s.w.s.u.m.OrServerWebExchangeMatcher : Trying to match using PathMatcherServerWebExchangeMatcher{pattern='/logout', method=POST}
2024-04-14T14:54:22.214-07:00 DEBUG 35903 --- [api-gateway] [     parallel-3] athPatternParserServerWebExchangeMatcher : Request 'GET /eureka/web' doesn't match 'POST /logout'
2024-04-14T14:54:22.214-07:00 DEBUG 35903 --- [api-gateway] [     parallel-3] o.s.s.w.s.u.m.OrServerWebExchangeMatcher : No matches found
2024-04-14T14:54:22.215-07:00 DEBUG 35903 --- [api-gateway] [     parallel-3] a.DelegatingReactiveAuthorizationManager : Checking authorization on '/eureka/web' using org.springframework.security.authorization.AuthenticatedReactiveAuthorizationManager@1c50770f
2024-04-14T14:54:22.215-07:00 DEBUG 35903 --- [api-gateway] [     parallel-3] ebSessionServerSecurityContextRepository : No SecurityContext found in WebSession: 'org.springframework.web.server.session.InMemoryWebSessionStore$InMemoryWebSession@8fb70c6'
2024-04-14T14:54:22.216-07:00 DEBUG 35903 --- [api-gateway] [     parallel-3] o.s.s.w.s.a.AuthorizationWebFilter       : Authorization failed: Access Denied
2024-04-14T14:54:22.219-07:00 DEBUG 35903 --- [api-gateway] [     parallel-3] ebSessionServerSecurityContextRepository : No SecurityContext found in WebSession: 'org.springframework.web.server.session.InMemoryWebSessionStore$InMemoryWebSession@8fb70c6'

Since the last log indicates I don't have InMemoryWebSessionStore, I also tried to create a SecurityConfig class inside the DiscoverServer/config package as well.
This the code for that
package com.sbmicroservices.discoveryserver.config;

@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.csrf(csrf -> csrf.ignoringRequestMatchers("/eureka/**"));
        return httpSecurity.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public InMemoryUserDetailsManager userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails user = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                .username("user")
                .password("password")
                .build();
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
    }
}


enable DEBUG logs and update your post to include them so we can just read the reason for the 401 than sit here and guess
